# WordPress JWT Authentication

Tags: php, authentication

Can you give me an idea of how can i implement WordPress JWT in the below problem statement?

I need to add JWT Authentication to my WordPress website.
We are developing an external app that needs to share authentication with our WP website. The external app will be located in a sub-domain.

**The important thing here is that once users are logged into the WP website, they are also logged into the external app.**

Think of how when you l**og into Gmail you're also logged into YouTube**.

At this stage, we don't need additional security layers such as MFA, etc.

Let me know your thoughts!